# Filter table + virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard

I have a page with a jquery table filter and it works fine with a regular keyboard but not with a virtual keyboard.

Check the JSFiddle to see what I mean, below is the code for the filter function.

https://jsfiddle.net/e3r76kdc/5/

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    _this = this;
    // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
    $.each($("#table tbody").find("tr"), function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) == -1)
           $(this).hide();
        else
             $(this).show();                
    });
});
```

If you type the numbers on a regular keyboard it filters the table but if you use the virtual keyboard the numbers appears but the filter doesn't work.

I bet it's something simple but I'm having trouble solving it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the virtual keyboard will not trigger the `keyup` event. I checked the source and it does however trigger a focus on the input.

Therefore you can simply do:

`$("#search").on('keyup focus', function() { ...`

https://jsfiddle.net/e3r76kdc/6/